# In Angular how to change the route template using a controller function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

When loading the url at first, I need to display the initial template. But after clicking a link, I need to

1. Get it's href value (It's the current template url with some extra params)
2. Send the new url with params to the server
3. Get the new template (The server will send a new template with new data)
4. Change the view accordingly (Update the whole page)

I have managed to complete the first task. The 4th task is the real problem. Changing the route's template using the function which gets called when clicking the link (With ng-click). How can I do it?

Comment: Define something. Follow Us. Impress the Boss. This will not happen here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do in order to replace current template with the new one is basically two lines of code. Namely:

1. update current `$templateCache` for the currently used template;
2. reload current route.

It could look something like this:

```
var content = '<h2>New content loaded previously</h2>';
var templateName = $route.current.templateUrl;

$templateCache.put(templateName, content);
$route.reload();
```

Check the simple demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/V5AG0UXS3b8wBwxrz7qO?p=preview

Comment: Fixed the problem! Now it works! Now need to figure out how to get the template from the url

Comment: Just used http.get to get the content! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

To get the URL of your current template :

```
$route.current.templateUrl
```

You can try to set template value directly (never test)

```
$route.current.templateUrl = "http://myrul.tld";
```

You can see the doc at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route